# Create a table using data content as columns in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I currently have raw data like this:

```
person1  person2   person3...
  blue     red      green
  red      blue     yellow
  black    black
  white    green
  orange
```

with lots of different values and columns.

What I need is:

```
         Blue  Red  Black  Green Yellow Orange White
Person1   Y     Y     Y                    Y     Y
Person2   Y     Y     Y      Y
Person3                      Y      Y
```

Any suggestions please?

Thanks

Comment: How is this data stored? In a file? data frame?

Comment: Hey, stored as a csv file so excel table format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use `get_dummies` (you can add `map({True:'Y',False:''})` at the end )

```
s=pd.get_dummies(df1)
s.columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(s.columns.str.split('_').map(tuple))
Yourdf=s.stack(0).sum(level=1).eq(1)
Yourdf
Out[132]: 
         black   blue  green  orange    red  white  yellow
person1   True   True  False    True   True   True   False
person2   True   True   True   False   True  False   False
person3  False  False   True   False  False  False    True
```

Or

```
pd.concat([df1[x].str.get_dummies() for x in df1.columns],keys=df1.columns,axis=1).\
        stack(1).sum(level=1).T.eq(1)
Out[164]: 
         black   blue  green  orange    red  white  yellow
person1   True   True  False    True   True   True   False
person2   True   True   True   False   True  False   False
person3  False  False   True   False  False  False    True
```

Answer (score 3):

**Method 1**: [`DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) + `pd.value_counts`

```
new_df=df.apply(pd.value_counts).replace({1:'Y',np.nan:''}).T
print(new_df)

        black blue green orange red white yellow
person1     Y    Y            Y   Y     Y       
person2     Y    Y     Y          Y             
person3                Y                       Y
```

---

**Method 2**: [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) + [`DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html)

```
df2=df.melt()
new_df=pd.crosstab(df2['variable'],df2['value']).replace({0:'',1:'Y'}).rename_axis(index=None,columns=None)
print(new_df)
        black blue green orange red white yellow
person1     Y    Y            Y   Y     Y       
person2     Y    Y     Y          Y             
person3                Y                       Y
```

Comment: ansev, for you first method to work i needed to run new_df1 = new_df1.drop(new_df1.columns[0], axis=1) . What version are you running? I upvoted you.

Comment: I use 0.25.2, You can also try: `new_df=df.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts()).replace({1:'Y',np.nan:''}).T`. Thanks by upvote:)

Answer (score 0):

I have a primitive approach using dictionary data type and print function,

```
columns = ("Blue", "Red", "Black", "Green", "Yellow", "Orange", "White")

table_dict = {"Person1": ("Y", "Y", "Y", " ", " ",  "Y", "Y"),
          "Person2": ("Y", "Y", "Y", "Y ", " ", " ", " "),
          "Person3": (" ", " ", " ", "Y", "Y", " ", " ")}

print(" "*5, *columns, sep=" "*5)

for person in table_dict:
    print(person, end=" "*4)
    print(*table_dict.get(person), sep=" "*9)
```

Output:

```
          Blue     Red     Black     Green     Yellow     Orange     White
Person1    Y         Y         Y                             Y         Y
Person2    Y         Y         Y         Y                               
Person3                                  Y         Y
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a working implementation, let me know what you think:

```
d1={'person1': ['blue', 'red', 'black', 'white', 'orange'], 'person2': ['red', 'blue', 'black', 'green', ''], 'person3': ['green', 'yellow', '', '', '']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
new_df1 = df1.apply(pd.value_counts).replace({1:'Y',np.nan:''})
new_df1 = new_df1.reset_index().drop(df1.index[0]).T

new_df1
             1     2      3       4    5      6       7
index    black  blue  green  orange  red  white  yellow
person1      Y     Y              Y    Y      Y        
person2      Y     Y      Y            Y               
person3                   Y                           Y
```